# Silverlight Windows Phone App with WCF on Device

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-8

I have hosted WCF service in my pc under local IIS, and added Service Reference in Silverlight Windows Phone using my PC IP, So, when I install app on device for testing, should both(PC and Phone)networks be same?If I change network on my phone, I am getting error. Is it the limitation?

```
"System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException".
```

I read somewhere that, Both Networks should be same.

Comment: Are you using full blown IIS or the built-in web dev server in Visual Studio or IIS Express? Also make sure to open any ports via Windows Firewall.

Comment: @CamBruce thank you brother for reply, full blown means what? I have selected Local IIS from project properties and created virtual directory,Port is 80 and running. Please guide me.

Comment: Have you granted a firewall exception for Port 80?

Comment: @CamBruce but I am able to browse service from IIS Manager "inetmgr"

Comment: @CamBruce I am not using IIS Express Port, so still do I need to grant?

Comment: The windows phone emulator uses hyper-v, so it is a completely different machine on your network, with a different IP address, so it is accessing your server as if it was a different server on the network, so yes, you need an exception for port 80.

Comment: @CamBruce so, what should I do?Shall I able to test app on any different network until submit on app store?

Comment: @CamBruce If I grant Port 80, then will app run on any netowrk?

Comment: Are you using a physical device or the phone emulator?

Comment: @CamBruce physical device, that is the point that I was asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the machine that is hosting the WCF service does not have external, public IP address, you will have to connect your physical device via WI-FI to the same network the server is on. You also need to open port 80 on the server, so your device can access the service.

Comment: thank you brother,thank you so much, so after submitting to windows store, should I continue to open my port 80?

Comment: Yes, you would need to both open port 80, and have a public IP address. Ideally, you would host the WCF Service in Azure or AWS, where you can easily get a public IP & host name.

Comment: thank you man, you made it for me, where do I submit? I am creating windows phone silverlight, so I think it is Windows Phone Store, is it so?